# Open email popup on enter key hit on email address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I have email address shown on my screen on which user can click and outlook mail instance get opened (used simple `<a mailto:/>` ). However, user can also use a tab sequence to come on that email address and press enter. I want to open outlook mail instance in a similar fashion on it. How can I do it?

Comment: That's browser functionality, and not within your control. That said, it works here in Firefox at least.

Comment: Works in Chrome as well. There should not be any difference between pressing enter when focusing a link and clicking on it. What browser are you using?

Comment: Well...I am using IE. I created separate application and it worked. On debugging, realized that there is some other js error on my application page due which this was not working. Thanks for replies and appologies for wasting time. I would like to delete this post as it is not actual technical problem but not able to since it has replies. can anybody please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onkeypress="check()">

function check(e)
{
    if (!e) e = window.event;   // resolve event instance
  if (e.keyCode == '13')
    {
      //your code for opening outlook
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="BAC" id="mail"/>
$(function(){
  $("#mail").bind('keyup',function(evt){
        var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : evt.which;
        if(key==13) return true;
        else return false;
  }); 
});
```